# Oauth2; How to solve the issue with expired AccessToken during multiple async api calls , made concurrently?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm using Spring Security Oauth2 as a security layer in my application. Everything worked well until concurrently  async  calls appeared .

Can someone tell me how to handle the next case : 
 
1. The client has an accessToken which already has expired.
 
2. The client makes two concurrent async api calls to my api ( for example : Thread1, Thread2). 
 
3. The Thread1  receives an error : "accessToken expired", before Thread2 . 
 
4. By using  the refreshToken  Thread1  receives a new accessToken = qqqqq. 
 
5. The Thread2  receives an error : "accessToken expired", before Thread1  makes a new call to server with the new accessToken = qqqqq . 
 
6. By using  the refreshToken  Thread2  receives a new accessToken = wwwww and removes the accessToken = qqqqq . 
 
7. Here , the Thread1  makes a call to server with accessToken = qqqqq which is not active. 
 
8. Theoretically, it is quite possible to loop both Threads by invalidating  each other.

I will appreciate any help , thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you've got control over the client then you can attach a version number to the access token - if a thread attempts to refresh the access token using an old version number then the current (recently refreshed) access token is returned instead.

```java
public class AccessToken {
  private int currentVersion;
  private String accessToken;

  private static AccessToken currentToken;

  public static synchronized AccessToken refresh(AccessToken token) {
    if(token.currentVersion == currentToken.currentVersion) {
      AccessToken newToken = // refresh token
      newToken.currentVersion = currentToken.currentVersion + 1;
      currentToken = newToken;
    }
    return currentToken;
  }
}
```

If you don't have any control over the client and/or would prefer to fix this server-side, then a few options are:

1. Allow the client to use one access token per thread instead of requiring them to share one global access token across threads.
2. Forbid refreshing the access token more than once every, say, 5 seconds.  This way even if the client runs into a refresh loop they ought to still be able to make some progress.
3. Expose a method that will only refresh the token if the correct current token is provided so that the client can conditionally update its access token (you'll still need to expose the current method to absolutely refresh the token in case the client forgets the old access token).

Comment: Thank you very much . 
I have control over the client  so I will use "accessToken"  version  .
Thank you again.

Comment: My Java is rusty but in the example code there is still a race condition, right?  Two threads could potentially see that the token is the current version and then try to do a refresh, with one indeterminately overwriting the other.

Comment: Do you have some code example for the 2nd point on server side?